# ÖBB train no reservation seats

Tags: tickets, prague, salzburg

[image]

I am booking a train from Salzburg to Prague but I can only reserve a seat from Salzburg to Linz (Linz to Prague no reservation provided) What happens with this situation? do I have a seat on that day?

Comment: Where did you try to book? [OBB](https://www.oebb.at/en) seems to have an option to book including a reservation.

Comment: I just noticed that seat reservation is only possible in first class. A first class supplement can be bought at the OBB site for €0 though.

Comment: I could see the option to reserve a seat from both OBB and CD... Would you mind to share which date you are trying to book?

Comment: Similar question. At least my answer deals with this situation as well: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/176003/why-cant-i-reserve-a-seat-on-the-eurocity-train-i-just-bought-a-ticket-for-on-%c3%96/176006#176006

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, the reservation period for EC330, at least at the moment, only starts 30 days before the scheduled departure day, although Czech railways ([České dráhy](https://www.cd.cz/en/default.htm), CD) usually allow reservation up to 60 days in advance. But many operational factors, especially unpredictable for certain international routes, may impact [when the reservation opens](https://www.seat61.com/european-train-booking-horizons.htm). [The exact time for the opening of the reservation period may vary significantly.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/176003/why-cant-i-reserve-a-seat-on-the-eurocity-train-i-just-bought-a-ticket-for-on-%C3%96/176006#176006)

It is possible to book a reservation for EC330 departure on October 21, 2022 on both OBB and CD. However, if I try October 22, 2022, the CD website prompts that "the booking period for this reservation has not yet begun or has already expired." (This answer is written on September 21, 2022.)

[image]

If no reservation is possible at all, e.g. for certain regional trains, CD website would display "Cannot be reserved", instead of prompting being outside of the reservation period.

[image]

Reservation is not mandatory on EC330, you may simply take any non-reserved seats (if available) when getting on the train. Of course, if there are a lot of travellers on a particular day, there is a chance that you will have to stand during part of the journey

Comment: (+1) Good catch, do you mind adding a word on what happens when there really are no seat reservation and then I would delete my answer?

Comment: I meant how seating works in reservation-free trains, sorry, but that's definitely useful as well!

Comment: I believe that you now can reserve seats 30 days in advance is just a coincidence and not the rule. I took the same train in the opposite direction just a few weeks ago and couldn't reserve a seat until about a week before departure. I am not sure why, but I have had the exact same problem with many other trains running into, out of or through Austria this summer.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Thanks, I'll link to your answer to the other question.